# Move File to new location where Parent Folder Name Matches

Tags: powershell, rollback, copy-item

#### Problem

I am working on a rollback feature in my application in which I copy the files from a backup/rollback directory to a destination folder. As simple as that sounds, this is where it gets complicated. Due to all the files sharing the same or similar name, I used the parent folder as the anchor to help enforce unique locations.

I want to essentially recursively search a directory and wherever a folder name matches a parent directory of an object, paste a copy of the object into that folder, overwriting whatever file(s) share a name with said object.

A more visible way to represent this would be:

```
$Path = C:\Temp\MyBackups\Backup_03-14-2017
$destination = C:\SomeDirectory\Subfolder
$backups = GCI -Path "$Path\*.config" -Recursive

foreach ($backup in $backups) {
    Copy-Item -Path $backup -Destination $destination | Where-Object {
        ((Get-Item $backup).Directory.Name) -match "$destination\*"
    }
}
```

However, the above doesn't work and none of my research is finding anything remotely similar to what I'm trying to do.

#### Question

Does anyone know how to Copy an Item from one location to another in which the parent folder of the copied item matches a folder in the destination using PowerShell?

Comment: could you give me a quick example of what your talking about with the files and folders?

Comment: Ex01: The location of the item to be copied is `C:\Temp\MyBackups\FolderX\web.config`  the location I wish to search through would be `C:\MyApp\Source\SomeFolder\ `. I would have the web.config to be restored to `C:\MyApp\Source\SomeFolder\FolderX\ ` and overwrite any existing web.config  found in the folder

Comment: For one thing you cannot filter after the fact (`Copy-Item ... | Where-Object {...}`). Also, does the content of your backup directory resemble the structure of the destination, i.e. are the relative paths inside backup and destination folder identical?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Yes they are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the backed-up files, replace the source base path with the destination base path, then move the files. If you only want to replace existing files, test if the destination exists:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.config' -Recursive | ForEach-Object {
    $dst = $_.FullName.Replace($Path, $destination)
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst) {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dst -Force
    }
}
```

If you want to restore files that are missing in the destination make sure to create missing directories first:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.config' -Recursive | ForEach-Object {
    $dst = $_.FullName.Replace($Path, $destination)
    $dir = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($dst)
    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dir -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Type Directory -Path $dir | Out-Null
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dst -Force
}
```

Comment: Oh! That makes a lot of sense... I really was overthinking this. Thank you Ansgar

Answer (score 0):

You may be over thinking this. If you are backing up a web.config file from a website, I'd highly advise using the SiteID as the backup folder. Then simply utilize this as the means to find the right folder to copy the web.config file to when you want to rollback.

Ideally when working with any group of items (in this instance websites) try to find a unique identifier for the items. SiteIDs are ideal for this.

```
$Path = C:\Temp\MyBackups\Backup_03-14-2017  #In this directory store the web.config's in directories that match the SiteID of the site they belong to
#For example, if the site id was 5, then the full backup directory would be: C:\Temp\MyBackups\Backup_03-14-2017\5 
$backups = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include *.config -Recurse

foreach ($backup in $backups) 
{
    $backupId = $backup.Directory.Name
    $destination = (Get-Website | where {$_.id -eq $backupId}).physicalPath

    Copy-Item -Path $backup -Destination $destination 
}
```

Comment: Ah, that would be exceptionally useful, except, my problem involves backing up a local repository rather than a website.